# How to repeat a plot in different subplots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have

```
fig, (((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4))) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2, 
                                               sharex='col', 
                                               sharey='row', 
                                               figsize=(12, 12))
```

and I want to repeat one plot, say P in all axes, something like:

```
P.plot(ax = [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4], facecolor = "none",
       edgecolor = "black")
```

without having to repeat the line for each plot. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: what is `P`? Are you looking for an object `P` that would allow for the given command?

Comment: any reason you cannot use a for-loop? `for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]: ax.plot(...)`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: it's a `geopandas` `GeoDataFrame` with a `plot()` method.

Comment: @DizietAsahi: no reason. I wanted to learn whether there was a "pythonic" way to pass all axes without iterating over the axis. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people prefer to use `map` instead of `for` in python. So I suppose if the aim is to replace some canonical loop like

```
for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]:
    geodf.plot(ax=ax)
```

you could do

```
list(map(lambda ax: geodf.plot(ax=ax), [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do this using list comprehension method without having to write four separate plot commands *explicitly*. I am using a DataFrame as `p` to be consistent with your problem. You can try replacing `df` with your `p` variable.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4))) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2, 
                                               sharex='col', 
                                               sharey='row', 
                                               figsize=(8, 8))

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   "y" : [1, 4, 9, 16]})

_ = [df.plot(x="x", y="y", ax=ax) for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]]
plt.show()
```

[image]